# What is oscillatory convection?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, convection

I come across this term in a lot of papers which talk about convection and instabilities but could not find a proper explanation of what oscillatory convection is. Is it the fluid which is oscillating or something else?

Comment: Please add a reference.

Answer (score 1):

In a two layer system, there are various mode of convection,  two of them are mechanical coupling and thermal coupling. When the system oscillates between these two modes, it's oscillatory mode of convection.